# Swipe div on touch like in ipad's mail app

Tags: jquery, touch

I'm developing a mobile app written in jquery/css, and need to swipe an element to show some button underneath.
The effect and layout is similar to the mail side list, in which you can partially slide out the mail button to show contextual delete / archive buttons.

Just for reference
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tCYAercOuEo

I started with jqueryui droppable, but found soon that it doesen't work with touch events, so tried some plugin to enable it, but are too much in beta to be used.

What is the best option to achieve that effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am looking to do the same as you so cant help too much yet but here's something you may find useful:

```
http://pep.briangonzalez.org/ 
https://github.com/ksloan/jquery-mobile-swipe-list
http://skidding.github.io/dragdealer/
```